# jquery lightbox,popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I want to add on a div a description text, and when a user click's on that text I want to appear a lightbox or popup with some external content. 
How do I make this?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to use a lightbox plugin? Like http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some sample code of the "div a description text" you are going to have setup. Setting up a lightbox is usually fairly simple if your using jQuery I would find a plugin that does what you need and then the code will be something similar to this

```
function descPopUp(){
     $("#divid a").lightbox();
     //or a class could be use on the anchor text
     //also some functions might require you to bind it to click
     $("#divid a").click(function(){
          $("#id").lightbox();
       });
 }
```

I am guessing your html will look something like this

```
<div id="someid">
   content
 <a href="#" class="desc" onclick="javascript:descPopUp()">Description text</a>
</div>
```